# It is possible to suspend a call on Android programatically?

Tags: android

Good afternnon, the question is if there is a way to suspend a call when another call is receive and swap between the "on hold" calls programatically.

Ps: It is possible to record calls without using the mic of the device? i mean, acess the call audio?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not on a standard device. The only app which can access the telephony stack is the phone app, which is cooked into the phone and had special permissions. Most phones also do not enable the input audio path between the phone stack and media layers, so you can't record the audio while in-call or try to inject your own audio.

Comment: Thanks @Larry! i'm sorry if i'm bother you but is possible to automatic play a DTMF digit or sequece during call on Android app ? 

and it is possible to do a WAP / Internet call but allows user to
define a specific APN/number and authentication
parameters.

It's for a university project, thanks in advance.

Comment: See the `Call` class, introduced in API 23. Prior to that there is no standard way for a 3rd party app to play DTMF while in-call, unless the app is a SIP app and then it controls the audio paths.